# What is the advantage of a static function?

Tags: c, function, static, static-functions

The declaration below:

```c
static int *foo();
```

declares `foo` as a static function returning a pointer to an `int`.

What's the purpose of declaring a function as static ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function's name isn't visible outside the translation unit (source file) in which it's declared, and won't conflict with another function `foo` in another source file.

In general, functions should probably be declared `static` unless you have a specific need to call it from another source file.

(Note that it's only the *name* that's not visible.  It can still be called from anywhere in the program via a pointer.)

Comment: What is the difference between marking a function as static and simply not including it in the header? Won't omitting it from the header have the same effect? Or, is there a reason to not put something in the header and also not mark it as static?

Comment: @Alex: Including its declaration in the header makes it visible to the compiler, and thereby to other source files that include that header.  Making it non-`static` makes its name visible to the linker; other source files can access it by declaring it themselves.  As a matter of style, either (a) declare it static, or (b) declare it non-static *and* include its declaration in the corresponding .h file.  (If C had a full-fledged module system, guidelines like this wouldn't be necessary.)

Answer (score 6):

It prevents other translation units (.c files) from seeing the function. Keeps things clean and tidy. A function without `static` is `extern` by default (is visible to other modules).

Answer (score 4):

From the C99 standard:

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identiﬁers**
>
> If the declaration of a ﬁle scope identiﬁer for an object or a function contains the storage-class speciﬁer static, the identiﬁer has internal linkage.

and

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each
> declaration of a particular identiﬁer with external linkage denotes the same object or
> function. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identiﬁer with internal
> linkage denotes the same object or function. Each declaration of an identiﬁer with no
> linkage denotes a unique entity.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a function as `static` prevents other files from accessing it. In other words, it is only visible to the file it was declared in; a "local" function.

You could also relate `static` (function declaration keyword, not variable) in C as `private` in object-oriented languages.

See [here](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/cref-mleslie/SYNTAX/static.htm) for an example.

Comment: The question is about [tag:c].  What's a "class"?

Comment: i am more concern with c ...i dont know class & c++

Comment: @Keith: Apologies - been coding solely in Java for the past month.

Answer (score 3):

Marking a function or a global variable as `static` makes it invisible to the linker once the current translation unit is compiled into an object file.

In other words, it only has internal linkage within the current translation unit. When not using `static` or explicitly using the `extern` storage class specifier, the symbol has external linkage.